# How to extract the direct facebook video url as mp4

Tags: android, facebook, video

I am trying to extract the url for facebook video file page from the facebook video link but I am not able to proceed how.

For example: The facebook video url I have is: https://www.facebook.com/nerdandco/videos/1662140250706521/

The facebook video file url I want to extract is: https://video-ord1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hvideo-xpf1/v/t42.1790-2/12616394_491864644347782_1646982338_n.mp4?efg=eyJybHIiOjU2NywicmxhIjo1MTIsInZlbmNvZGVfdGFnIjoidjNfNDI2X2NyZl8yM19tYWluXzMuMF9zZCJ9&rl=567&vabr=315&oh=333a80044ec836e9b2228afb58cba6c1&oe=56A51D9B

in Java (Android), should I use FB SDK? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: facebook itself tries to make you unable to get the video file url. So there is no official way to do that (AFAIK). Using unofficial ways will *probably* violate facebook rules, and you risk to get your app banned at google play

Comment: Via API you will only be able to get the `source` field for videos on pages that you (resp. the app user whose token you are using) have an administrative role on; for just general pages there is no way to get this via API.

Comment: Thank you, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## FacebookUrlExtractor

Note : This repository not maintained any more, but you can check my logic's

### **`Example`**

```
  new FacebookExtractor(this,"Video Url",false)
    {
        @Override
        protected void onExtractionComplete(FacebookFile facebookFile) {
            Log.e("TAG","---------------------------------------");
            Log.e("TAG","facebookFile AutherName :: "+facebookFile.getAuthor());
            Log.e("TAG","facebookFile FileName :: "+facebookFile.getFilename());
            Log.e("TAG","facebookFile Ext :: "+facebookFile.getExt());
            Log.e("TAG","facebookFile SD :: "+facebookFile.getSdUrl());
            Log.e("TAG","facebookFile HD :: "+facebookFile.getHdUrl());
            Log.e("TAG","---------------------------------------");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onExtractionFail(Exception error) {
            Log.e("Error","Error :: "+error.getMessage());
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    };
```

### **`gradle`**

```
dependencies 
 {
    implementation 'com.github.Ashusolanki:FacebookUrlExtractor:0.0.4'
 }
```

For More https://github.com/Ashusolanki/FacebookUrlExtractor

Comment: Thanks Ashvin. But there is one problem.  fb_extracter.cancel(true)  this cancel function does not work. Please help me

Comment: Hi sir please open issue on repository i will solve it as soon as possible

Comment: Hi Ashvin,
In this library we are getting just 1 link. I want to both Link HD and SD. Is there any solution to get both link through your build library. Thank you

Comment: @ShafqatKamal Thank You Sir

Comment: tried it but it is not working, i cannot even import the class (compile sdk 32)

Comment: @Sam sorry for this solution is outdated, you can clone and modify the code

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you want to achieve here, but if you are trying to [download a Facebook video to mp4](http://facebookmp4.com) from the URL you can perhaps use an [online Facebook video downloader](https://video-converter-mp4.com/fb-downloader/). 
Facebook does not allow the extraction of private videos though.